# I can't paste to vim from external clipboard

Tags: linux, vim, termux

I use VIM via termux with and faced with the following ploblem i can't to paste data from external clipboard inside VIM. I checked that my vim installation support pasting from external clipboard via following command

```
:echo has('clipboard')
#its return me 1 but when
# i trying to paste in vim
#via "+p or "*p or Ctrl V or Ctrl Shift V
```

It is't paste anything. What i am doing wrong. Is it possible that i can't to paste data which is in Android clipboard

Comment: Try Ctrl+Shift+v

Comment: Nothing is happening(((

Comment: press i before anything, vim will go into insert mode by that.

Comment: use :reg to see where the clipboard is stored

Comment: :reg display what containing in clipboard but there isn't data which i copied from my browser

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem.  Vim package in termux have problems with recognizing android clipboard. If you faced with same problem do following.To access android clipboard via vim you should to install Termux-api that allow to accessing some android features than inside VIM type the following command

```
:r !termux-clipboard-get
```

You can add short-key mapping for it in .vimrc file just type

```
nnoremap <C-v> :r !termux-clipboard-get <CR>
```

Now i can use Ctrl V for paste in Vim
I sent bug report to termux github page that standart short-key "*p isn't working

Answer (score 1):

Add the following in .vimrc

```
au TextYankPost * call system('termux-clipboard-set &', @")
function Paste(p)
    let sysclip=system('termux-clipboard-get')
    if sysclip != @"
        let @"=sysclip
    endif
    return a:p
endfunction
noremap <expr> p Paste('p')
noremap <expr> P Paste('P')
```

This works for all copy, cut, and paste commands, including dw, 2p, etc.