# I can't copy from neovim to android clipboard

Tags: vim, neovim, termux

every time I try to make a ***"yy"*** or a **"dd"** or a **":%y"** to copy everything from neovim de termux to for example send my code by whatsapp I can't, I can only paste the last thing I copy by long pressing select the text and press copy, and you know that doing it in neovim or vim even the line numbers are copied, that's why I'm trying to do so that when copying I can paste it very quickly in another place on the slide

Example of the only way I can copy from there, and also there my init.vim or vimrc file:

```
"set directory
   1 set runtimepath^=~/.vim runtimepath+=~/.vim/after
   2 let &packpath = &runtimepath
   3
   4 "files
   5 so ~\.vim/plugins.vim
   6 so ~\.vim/plugin-config.vim
   7 so ~\.vim/maps.vim
   8
   9 set list
  10
  11 syntax enable
  12
  13 "show line number and relative number
  14 set nu-
  15 set rnu
  16 set numberwidth=1 "better show the numbers
  17
  18 "copy and paste with the mouse
  19 set mouse=a
  20
  21 "enable copy and paste 'yy, p'
  22 set clipboard=unnamed
  23 "set clipboard+=unnamedplus
  24
  25 "shows the pressed
  26 set showcmd
  27
  28 "Show current column
  29 set ruler
  30
  31 "perform indent
  32 set smartindent
  33
  34 "does not create external files
  35 set noswapfile
  36 set nobackup
  37
  38 "Seaching
  39 "moves to result as you type
  40 set incsearch
  41 "distinguish between upper and lower case when searching
  42 set smartcase
  43 "Highlight matches
  44 set hlsearch-
  45 "Unless they contain at least one capital letter
  46 set ignorecase-
  47
  48
  49 "tab of 4 spaces
  50 set noexpandtab
  51 set tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4
  52
  53 "Scheme
  54 colorscheme gruvbox
  55 let g:gruvbox_contrast_dark = "hard"
  56
  57 "highlight Normal ctermbg=NONE
  58 set laststatus=2
  59 set noshowmode
  60
  61 "Fonts
  62 set guifont=Hurmit_Nerd_Font_Mono:h12
  63
  64 "When a file is edited its indent file is loaded
  65 filetype plugin indent on
```

I explain it in more detail, I can paste normally I do not need to use that line that tells me to use ctrl + v, when I press esc then p, I can perform a good and normal paste, **however I cannot copy and paste anywhere else instead, in another application, etc.**

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61701614/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btermux%5D+clipboard

Comment: I tried, I already put the function that they also say about the ctrl + v, but no, none of those can help me @phd

Comment: add one more clarification in the question